# how to prevent application from closing itself

Tags: android

I have  developed a mdm server (mobile device manager) and an android application. I have manage to connect the two devices. In addition, I have wrote an android application ,which can work on any android platform. Now, I am trying to manage android application in a way it can not be closed without permission of me.In other words, android application will run from start of the cell phone until I have send a command to close itself.

I do not manage how I can do that. If you know, can you share your knowlege ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to have never ending applications on Android.

Whenever the system requires more resources for the current foreground task, it will kill background processes to free up RAM and CPU.

However, you could do one of the following:

**Return START_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT using a Service**

In your onStartCommand() for your service, return [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) or [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Use a push notification service like GCM to trigger your app's launch only when needed**

This is a much more battery efficient method, as your app isn't running when it isn't required. By integrating [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), you have the ability to send push notifications to your app via the Google Services already installed on every Google approved Android device (anything with Google Play on it). When the device receives your notification, it will launch and notify your application on the device, hence starting it.

Comment: This is my last question. Is it possible to change task manager so that it cannot be closed ?

Comment: As your help, I understand from application layer, I cannot manage my wish. I will search a way change android os, open source, so to achieve my goal

Comment: Beware that you have to install a new custom Android OS on your device. So it won't work on other devices.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, you cannot prevent the User killing your application. (Task killers etc)

But what you can do is create a Service and start/stop it via startService/stopService. And make it STICKY.

Android can kill a Service when it is low on resource, STICKY will make the Service start again.

Comment: Can you explain more about sticky, please ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a well known saying that "Prevention is better than cure", By These lines I mean You should try and enclose the suspected instruction with try, catch and Finally blocks.

An Application does not close itself until and unless an unexpected flaw or error has occurred. Therefore make sure You've enclosed the sensitive program instruction, such as connecting, looking up for the devices etc. and apply proper instructions in the finaly block. Your program will work according to your demands. Thanks

Comment: Applications may be terminated by Android if it needs more resources for the current foreground process.

Comment: @RaghavSood Maybe this is a ridiculus question. It is okey for me resource manager can kill the application as long as it restart the application. But, my question is how can I prevent a user can kill my application ?

Comment: @RaghavSood the reason is what ? I can do it with java in my desktop, I do not understand why it can not be done on the android

Comment: Because Android is a mobile system, and when compared to your desktop, the resources on a mobile devices are very limited. That is why the system might kill your app to free resources. The user is allowed to manually kill any app via settings if they want to, including pre installed system apps. This allows them to kill rogue battery hungry apps etc.

Comment: @RaghavSood : yes brother, that always happens whenever the CPU and RAM are needed. the users application must be made a critical system process. so that it gets on last of the termination list.

Comment: @RaghavSood In my cell phone, after 10-20 seconds I kill some application, I have shocked when I have seen the closed application has still running. I have a bit confused what you have said. Can you explain my case ?

Comment: @JayKandari Even if it is last on the list, it can still be terminated by the system, and it can be terminated at any point by the user manually, irrespective of its priority.

Comment: @coler'e Those are the applications that are being restarted after they've been killed, either because of the START_STICKY scenario, or because they're registered to receive broadcasts or Alarm Manager events.

Comment: @RaghavSood with the alarm manager, they are restarting the application if they are closed. Am I understand correctly ?

Comment: I agree @RaghavSood: yes it is possible for the system to terminate it's application whenever needed. lets now leave the answers to coler'e : what do you think now what should be done brother..

Comment: @JayKandari it is just a wonder. I have wrote many application, not for sell, which cannot be closed. ( Those are just hobby project. Not for making user mad )

Comment: when it comes to me, I always end up with restarting the phone. lol

Comment: @RaghavSood the other case -broadcasts-, can I send an command from mdm, every x miniseconds, to restart the application if it is closed?

Comment: but what is the main motive behind this functionality.

Comment: @coler'e Broadcasts are sent by the system and by other apps. You cannot initiate them if your app isn't running.